# How can I remove the file extension of a "set" file from it's name so that I can call the file?

Tags: batch-file

The title may not make all that much sense but I'm trying to make a batch file that helps automate the process of learning Java. In this case, I'm trying to make a program that automatically finds my directory where I store my Java project files, find the latest file, compiles the file and then runs it.

So far I have this:

```
@ECHO OFF
E:
cd \Documents\Java 
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo The most recently created file is %LAST%
javac %LAST%
java %LAST%
pause
```

Pause is just for debugging of sorts so I can see what it's saying before the window closes again.

At the moment as you can see, `%LAST%` is the latest file, and from running the program, it manages to compile it. But, my issue after this is that even though `%LAST%` changes itself to the ".class" file, I can't figure out a way to remove the `.class` bit from the freshly set `%LAST%` so that the java command can run it without returning the error along the lines of "cannot find class `<filename>.class` .

Anyone got any clues? 
Thanks

Comment: Whilst you've received advice for one part of your question, we need further information about the other part. Currently you've designed your code to use a fixed location, `E:\Documents\Java` for your Java project file directory path, and you I'll assume that you want that to be propagated automatically. In order for us, or any subsequent code, to make that dynamic determination, we need to know exactly what criteria is used to search for and find that path. Please note that we require you to fully qualify that location, including drive types, known part paths or specific files to locate.

Comment: Also, I'd be interested to know why you feel the need to use the filename without its extension as the argument to your Java commands.

Comment: I haven't had any issue with the drive paths and stuff and didn't realize that would be an issue or something that confuses people. It's just what's going on in my case, and it's just a second SSD in my laptop for storage, and I relocated my documents, downloads, etc. to that drive. As for the filename thing, the javac command creates a ".class" file, and the java command after that will not run a ".class" file, so to save time, I just want to remove the extension so it can run "java <filename>" instead of "java <filename.class>" which wouldn't work.

Comment: The issue is often that there can be many different types of drive available, network, fixed, usb etc. If your directory was on a network drive, it may need to be mapped/available at the time of the search. If the directory was usb only, then there'd be no need to search network and fixed drives etc. As you intended to automatically find the location, we'd need to know where you're looking for it, all drives and types could be very time intensive. Then we'd need to know what the criteria is that determines  exactly which directory you want, it could be a specific substring or file name.

Comment: Also, if the files or directories never carry hidden or system attributes, it would be a lot quicker to exclude those from the search. As I stated, we need to know more information in order to find that project directory path in the most robust and efficient manner.

Comment: Please do not add solutions to your questions! If you want to provide such post it as an answer, given that it is not just a copy of another answer and following [answer]...

Comment: Sorry for the answer update! Quite new here as you can see so my mistake. Also, to Compo, I may have stated my query badly. I didn't intend for it to be understood as automatically finding the folder where I store my projects, it was a pre-located folder which is just on my secondary drive in my laptop, internal not USB. Again I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open `cmd` and type `for /f` and see how variable expansion works. Here is a demo using your code:

```
@echo off
cd /d E:\Documents\Java 
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (
    echo %%i - Full filename:
    echo %%~ni - Name Only
    echo %%~xi - Extension Only
)
pause
```

Also you can see that it is not needed to set a variable. so should work as:

```
@echo off
cd /d E:\Documents\Java 
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (
    echo The most recently created file is %%i
    javac %%i
    java %%~ni
)
```

but if you are determined to do so, then you would need to change only this line in your original code:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set "LAST=%%~ni"
```